# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a Drawer Navigator set up, with various screens.

On one screen, I have a FlatList with a simple TouchableOpacity like below:

```
 <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() =>
                navigation.navigate("ViewProject", {
                  screen: "viewProject",
                  params: { projectID: item.projectID },
                })
              }
            >
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

The navigation works, going to the viewProject screen, but no matter what I seem to try the route.params just doesn't seem to exist.

```
  export default function viewProject({ route }) {
  const projID = route.params?.projectID ?? 0; // ERRORS with TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params')
  console.log(projID);
```

}

I'm using the latest React Native, Navigation etc and TypeScript.

My only success is setting the initialRouteParams on the createStackNavigator that feeds into the drawer, and yet that's only accessible via navigation.state.params:

```
const screens = {
  viewProject: {
    screen: viewProject,   
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      return {
        headerTitle: () => (
          <Header navigation={navigation} title={"View Project"} />
        ),
      };
    },
  },
};

const viewProjectStack = createStackNavigator(screens, {
  initialRouteParams: { projectID: 23 }, // This works, but it's static and I can't change it  
});
```

Thanks in advance.
Stewart

Answer (score 1):

You can pass like this:-

```
<Button
title="Go to Details"
onPress={() => {
  /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
  navigation.navigate('Details', {
    itemId: 86,
    otherParam: 'anything you want here',
  });
}}
```

/>

and receive like this:-

```
function DetailsScreen({ route, navigation }) {
 /* 2. Get the param */
 const { itemId } = route.params;
const { otherParam } = route.params;
 return (
 <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
 <Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>
 <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(otherParam)}</Text>
  );
  }
```

[source](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Hi Shan,

Thanks for your response, but I've already tried that and it didn't work. I get the same error. It seems that 'route' just isn't passed at all as an object.

Comment: what is version of your react navigation?

Comment: The version is 6.14.5

Comment: I think latest react navigation version is 5.  https://reactnavigation.org/versions

Comment: change your this line `const projID = route.params?.projectID ?? 0; ` to `const projID = route.params` and pass navigation in your function. Then try

Comment: Ahh, we may be onto something! I'm only running  react-navigation@4.3.9. When I run npm install react-navigation@latest, it still only updates to that version... presumably because that's the latest on NPM? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation

Comment: check version in your package.json file.

Comment: install navigation from the link which I have attach in answer.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I was already up to date: "@react-navigation/core": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.4.1","react-navigation": "^4.3.9",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.4.13",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.5.1",

Comment: all should be of same version, right? whether 4 or 5.

Comment: The latest version of react-navigation is react-navigation@4.3.9. For version 5 you need to install @react-navigation/native. Both are required, and I have both installed.

Comment: you can't go with both the version in same project as much I know. Read docs of react navigation clearly.

Comment: I think you're right! Looks like I've had both 4 and 5 version of react-navigation installed. Looks like I'm going to need to do some rewriting of the code before I can get it working in the latest version, but I'm hopeful this is the reason why it wasn't working. Thanks for your help, Shan! :)

Comment: It's fixed now. Thanks :)

Comment: @SMcDonald where was problem please ?